# extracting date using regex from the cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a following dataframe

```
column 1   Description                          Extracted Data
date       January 15,2020 is important day
```

I want to get following result

```
column 1   Description                          Extracted Data
date       January 15,2020 is important day     January 15,2020
```

```
df.loc[df['column 1']=='date','Extracted Data']=df['Description'].str.extract(r'((January)|[/. ])|(\d{1,2}|[/., ]|\d{4})')
```

but I ma not getting desired result.Instead, i ma getting dataframe with all NaN values.
How can I fix this?

Comment: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877816/regular-expression-of-different-format-of-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multi dot `.*` and digits.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column 1': ['date'], 'Description': ['January 15,2020 is important day']})
df['Extracted Data'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'(.*,\d{4})')
```

**Output:**

```
  column 1                       Description   Extracted Data
0     date  January 15,2020 is important day  January 15,2020
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:(Oneliner)

```
df['Extracted data'] = [re.match('[A-Za-z]+ \d{2},\d{4}',x)[0] for x in df['Description']]
```

output:

```
  column1                              Desc   Extracted data
0    date  January 15,2020 is important day  January 15,2020
```

Regex Link: https://regex101.com/r/ICDJCp/1

Answer (score 0):

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column 1': ['date'], 'Description': ['January 15,2020 is important day']})
df['Extracted Data'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: dparser.parse(x,fuzzy=True).strftime('%B %d %Y'))
print(df)
  column 1                       Description   Extracted Data
0     date  January 15,2020 is important day  January 15 2020
```